# google custom search engine control search results

Tags: google-search-console, google-custom-search

My question is simple, how do I make a certain page be find-able by a specific keyword.
cse it's working fine it just don't manage to find everything he supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Google custom works like google search, manipulating results may not be possible, however, check out the synonyms tab in google.com/cse.

Say your users search for `MBA` you can configure it to show results for `Master of Business Administration`